# Nullable primitive long function parameter, can you check if the passed value is indeed null?

Tags: java, null, long-integer, nullable

Functional is declared as:

```
Object functionName(@Nullable long inputPar)
```

`@Nullable` annotation accepts null as input parameter on the function call.

Could I, inside the function, write a condition asking if the `inputPar` is null?

`if(inputPar == null)` is invalid, since it's a primitive type. What would be the most efficient alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach is to realize that even though you have marked `inputPar` as `@Nullable`, it is *literally impossible* for it to be null.  Marking a parameter `@Nullable` does not actually *make* a primitive value able to be null.

The only way to make this "actually" nullable is to write `@Nullable Long inputPar`, and use the wrapper type instead of the primitive.

Comment: This actually makes a lot more sense. Thank you.